# NSPredicate issue in Swift 1.2

Tags: swift, core-data, ios8

Since updating my project to Swift 1.2 - I'm getting a "EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=...) exception when creating a NSPredicate instance.

This is how I create it:

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "width = %@ AND height = %@ AND lang = %@", width, height, language)
```

All the arguments have values. Any ideas what have changed in 1.2 that is causing this to fail?

Comment: are width and height NSNumbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try %d for width and height

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "width = %d AND height = %d AND lang = %@", width, height, language)
```

Comment: That solves the crashing - but I don't get any results from CD anymore. width and height are CGFloats in my code here, and Floats in the CD model. I tried creating the predicate like this: let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "width = %d AND height = %d AND lang = %@", NSNumber(float: Float(width)), NSNumber(float: Float(height)), language), but it doesn't seem to match any items.

Comment: NSPredicate(format: "width = %f AND height = %f AND lang = %@", Float(width),  Float(height), language)